# iPhone, XML for preload data

Tags: iphone, xml, core-data

I save XML file in Resources folder in xcode. And I parse it when application launches and use it for a default data set. I don't see any problem with this but people are talking about CoreData to handle a default data set. Can I just still use XML file for a default data? what is the disadvantage of using XML for default data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you're fine using an XML file, assuming that the data is small and you're not modifying it a lot. I use a CSV file for a couple of my apps and that's worked fine for me.

With that said, here are better answers to a similar question: [Plist vs SQLite vs Core Data for a rss reader type application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751286/plist-vs-sqlite-vs-core-data-for-a-rss-reader-type-application)

Comment: My data is not small... Is this a critical problem using XML for such a big data?

Comment: There is no real problem people are urging you to use Core Data because they have grow so familiar with Core Data that they can set up almost any data task in a few minutes. When you can that, you start storing everything in Core Data that doesn't fit in the User Defaults.