# Concerns about Core Data

Tags: core-data

I'm getting ready to dive into my first Core Data adventure. While evaluating the framework two questions came up that really got me thinking about using Core Data at all for this project or to stick with SQLite.

1. My app will heavily rely upon importing data from an external source. I'm aware that one can import into Core Data but handling complex relationships seems complicated and tedious. Is there an easy way to accomplish complex imports?
2. The app has to be able to execute complex queries spanning multiple tables or having multiple conditions. Building these predicates and expressions simply scares me...

Is it worth to take the plunge and use Core Data or should I stick with SQLite?

Comment: I know that question is a little bit old, but how did you solve your first point? I have a very similar scenario and it'd be very nice to hear your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite3/524301#524301) and [others](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2009/5/18/237007) have said before, Core Data is really an object-graph management framework. It manages the relationships between model objects, including constraints on their cardinality, and manages cascading deletes etc. It also manages constraints on individual attributes. Core Data just *happens* to also be able to persist that object graph to disk. It can do this in a number of formats, including XML, binary, and via SQLite. Thus, Core Data is really orthogonal to SQLite. If your task is dealing with an embedded SQL-compatible database, go with SQLite. If your task is managing the model layer of an MVC app, go with Core Data. In specific answers to your questions:

1. There is no magic that can automatically import complex data into any model. That said, it is relatively easy in Core Data. Taking a [multi-pass](https://web.archive.org/web/20130622041930/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174) [approach](https://web.archive.org/web/20081013001127/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdZ104Versioning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002989-SW4) and using the SQLite backend can help with memory consumption by allowing you to keep only a subset of the data in memory at a time. If the data sets can be kept in memory, you can write a custom persistent store format that reads/writes directly to your legacy data format from within Core Data (see the [Atomic Store Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AtomicStore_Concepts/Introduction/Introduction.html)).
2. Building a complex `NSPredicate` declaratively is somewhat verbose but shouldn't scare you. The [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html) is a good place to start. You can, of course, also write predicates using a string format, much like a string-formatted SQL statement. It's worth noting that, as described above, the predicates in Core Data are on the objects and object graph, not on the SQL tables. If you *really* want to think at the level of tables, stick with SQLite and write your own wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really speak to your first point.

However, regarding your second point, using Core Data means you don't have to really worry about complex queries since you can just pretend that all the relationships are properly established in memory already (Apple's implementation details aside). It doesn't matter how complex a join it might be in a database environment because you really aren't in a database environment. If you need to get the fourth child of the grandparent of your current object and then find that child's pet's name and breed, all you do is traverse up the object tree in code using a series of messages or properties. No worries about joins or anything. The only problem is it might be really slow depending on your objects' relationships, but I can't really speak accurately to that since I haven't actually implemented anything using Core Data (I've just read about it extensively on Apple's and others' websites).

Answer (score 0):

If the data importer from an external source is written based on the same core data model (for the targeted/destination side of the import) - nothing will be conceptually different as compare to using/updating the same data (through the core data stack from your actual application).

If you create the data importer without using the core data stack, make sure you learn well the db schema that would be generated/expected by the core data based model. There is nothing magic there - just make sure you follow how the cross entity relationships are implemented and how entity hierarchies are stored.

I had to create recently a data importer from Access database into the core data based Sqlite store as a .NET app. Once my destination core data model was define, I created a small app that populated the Sqlite store with randomly generated entities (including all the expected relationships). Then, I reverse engineered how the core data actually created the Sqlite store for the model and how it handles the relationships by learning from the generated and persisted data. Then, I implemented the .NET based importer/data-transformer according to my observations. At the end, I got perfect core data friendly data store that could be open an modified from the application that was using the core data stack on Mac OSX.