# Objective-C O/R Mapper for IPhone

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

My understanding is that sqllite is pretty much the only choice for database on the iphone.  Is there an O/R Mapper for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for object persistence, [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the obvious way to go.

There's also [FMDB](http://code.google.com/p/flycode/source/browse/trunk/fmdb). There are others, but look at Core Data first.

Comment: FMDB is not an ORM, but it's about all you've got if you have to work with an existing SQLite file/schema rather than letting Core Data handle the schema for you.

Answer (score 1):

Although Apple's [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework is [*not*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite3/524301#524301) an ORM, it may be what you are looking for. In particular, if what you want is to persist your object model to a database to make it possible to have object graphs that are larger than available memory or to make querying efficient, Core Data is a good solution. If, on the other hand, you are trying to find an ORM to work with an existing SQLite database, you're out of luck.