# C# or windows equivalent of OS X's Core Data?

Tags: c#, cocoa, core-data

I'm late to the boat and have only just now started using Core Data in OS X / Cocoa - it's incredible and is really changing the way I look at things.

Is there an equivalent technology in C# or the modern Windows frameworks?  i.e. having managed data types where you get saving, data management, deleting, searching all for free?

Also wondering if there's anything like this on Linux.

Comment: I was under the impression that C# was basically built on a data management foundation. Was I wrong about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not for C#, but,

For Windows and Linux, Core Data has been made a reality through [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/). This is not a solution for everybody, probably just a solution for a few, but is completely awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the closest thing to Core Data on Windows is the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx). Unfortunately, it's a lot lower level than Core Data. For example, you have to create and maintain your own database schema.

Comment: EF is "a lot lower level" in that it's an ORM, not an object graph management framework like Core Data. You cannot control the schema of the SQLite DB under Core Data and you can't use legacy DBs or other RDBMs with Core Data. The main point is, they are serving two different purposes, Core Data just Happens to use a SQLite DB underneath as an implementation detail. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite-3