# Core Data what would be the Windows Phone equivalent

Tags: windows-phone-7, core-data, windows-phone-8, porting

I was looking for some equivalent library or framework in Windows Phone SDK 7.5 or 8 that have a similar behavior as iOS Core Data.

Looking at StackOverflow I found this question: [C# or windows equivalent of OS X's Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997154/c-sharp-or-windows-equivalent-of-os-xs-core-data) but it doesn't quite solve the problem.

Is there an alternative for Core Data on Windows Phone SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't such a library/framework. The closest relative you have to Core Data in WP8 is Linq to SQL. But of course, Linq to SQL and Core Data are two different things, and their purposes are different as well.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't serialization the similar to core data.

http://www.j2i.net/blogEngine/post/2011/02/10/Simple-Data-Serialization-on-WP7.aspx