# Quickest datastore for iOS app

Tags: swift, xcode6

I need a datastore that will persist between app closes/opens.  Implementing a database is too elaborate and time consuming for this simple project.

This is for a very simple table list app that will have an entry form with no more than four fields.  That data will display in the table.

Between a plist file and Core Data, which would be the most efficient way to go?

Comment: How about a plain ol' text file, assuming you don't need indexing?

Comment: FWIW, Dr. Dobbs seems to recommend SQLite: http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/ios-data-storage-core-data-vs-sqlite/240168843?pgno=2

Comment: Like I said, a database is too elaborate for this.  For the text file or plist, you have to roll everything.  I'm learning toward Core Data since it already has so much built out.  I've just never used it so I'm not entirely sure if it will be faster than text file or plist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some advantages of using Core Data? (as opposed to plist)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377274/what-are-some-advantages-of-using-core-data-as-opposed-to-plist)

Comment: @Bluehound: Nope.  You didn't read the question.  Core Data is only one part of the question.  plist is the other and as you can see below, NSUserDefaults is likely the solution.  So not sure what you try to force the answer as being Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How about `NSUserDefaults`?**

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

**Saving data:**

```
userDefaults.setValue(yourObject, forKey: "yourKey")
```

or:

```
userDefaults.setObject(yourObject, forKey: "yourKey")
```

**After saving new data, dont forget to call:**

```
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

**Loading saved data (after app close etc):**

```
var yourObject = userDefaults.valueForKey("yourKey")
```

or

```
var yourObject = userDefaults.objectForKey("yourKey")
```

Comment: Would I just store the entire array?  I don't think this would work well if I try storing each table worth of data.  All that data will be in an array and it seems managing storage of the array would be easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Sugar Record. It's a nice wrapper for Core Data which really simplifies things, easy to get up and running and most things can be done with a few lines of code.

https://github.com/SugarRecord/SugarRecord

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage of using a plist file is probably simplicity. However, if you have a lot of data, want to organize it elegantly in a table view, or basically want to do any higher end things, Core Data offers powerful features for such things, and is better on memory management. A simple table list app that uses a tableview to organize data, I would recommend using Core Data because of its `NSFetchedResultsController` class, which only loads necessary data, and has useful delegate methods for when the managed object context is modified.
For a complete implementation of an `NSFetchedResultsController`, see this [GitHub Project](https://github.com/iMac239/CoreDataSegueDemo).