# Data model persistence considerations in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I've been working with sqlite database in my iOS app for data persistence, and I'm now trying to decide if it is worth to learn Core Data. I've been reading some documentation and posts regarding its pros and cons, but I find that deciding when to use Core Data or Sqlite is not so clear (for example, [Core Data VS Sqlite or FMDB…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723923/core-data-vs-sqlite-or-fmdb)).

I need some guidance to know if I should learn and use Core Data, or using Sqlite is enough for me:

1. Already having sqlite scripts, is it possible to build a Core Data model from data in sqlite database? Afaik, (correct me if I'm wrong) you can use sqlite to persist Core Data objects, but is it possible to operate in reverse?
2. Is it appropiate Core Data for handling several users data? I need to take into account that different users could log in into the app in the same device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have two major products, one uses Core Data and the other uses FMDB. I greatly prefer using FMDB.  The Core Data stuff seems Arcane and not-straightfoward and it has really been a pain for me to work with.  Using the predicates, as opposed to simple queries has been a pain as well.  FMDB just works, and has been pleasant.  It handles multiple multiple people signing in, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is a wonderful framework but while it generally uses SQLite behind the scenes, you shouldn't think of Core Data as a database engine, but rather more of an object persistence framework. If you've got a lot of SQL code (especially bulk updates and the like), it might not be worth converting to Core Data. But Core Data has lots of wonderful performance optimizations, iCloud integration, etc., so it's worth examining in greater detail.

If you want background on Core Data, I'd suggest the Apple video [Working with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/ios/?id=36).

If you just want to simplify your SQLite code, check out [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

---

In answer to your questions:

> Already having sqlite scripts, is it possible to build a Core Data model from data in sqlite database? Afaik, (correct me if I'm wrong) you can use sqlite to persist Core Data objects, but is it possible to operate in reverse?

You generally have to redefine your Core Data model. It cannot just open your existing SQLite database (though once you define your model, you could write code to transfer the data from SQLite to Core Data).

> Is it appropiate Core Data for handling several users data? I need to take into account that different users could log in into the app in the same device.

Yes, you could. You'd have to define your model to handle this manually, though (e.g. add a user identifier field and manually code predicates/filters results accordingly, much like you'd have to do in SQLite).

Answer (score 1):

AppsDev,

Only you can judge whether to use Core Data or to stick with SQLite. As you've referenced my answer above, you know my view -- use Core Data. Let me put it in your context.

The big win is the family of abstractions that come with Core Data and how they map onto the Objective-C object model. This is something you have to handle manually from a SQLite application. (Can you do it? Yes. You will, though, most likely make a custom interface that is tuned to your SQL schema. It will have little reusability. This is a long term problem.)

As to the question of predicates versus SQL queries, this is a difference in world view. That said, as predicates can be applied to both NSSets and NSArrays, they have a utility beyond that required by Core Data. Knowing how to use predicates will be of value. For example, you could easily perform a query to get a collection of records and then use predicates to filter them, say for the search of a table view.

Everyone needs to pick when they are ready to embrace a specific pattern. SQL experts, unsurprisingly, like to stick with what they know. Dynamic language aficionados will choose differently. For iOS/OS X, embracing the dynamic language path will have ever increasing value to you as a developer.

Hence, my recommendation remains: use Core Data.

Andrew