# What is the best way to store data for a program about restaurant?

Tags: xcode, macos, sqlite, core-data

I want to make a program for a restaurant, to hold foods and store customer recipe. What is the best way to store data? (core data - sqlite - ...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data vs SQLite 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a conversation about core data vs. sqlite [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite-3). But, with iOS 5.0 you get the added benefit of being able to use iCloud file-sync for free if you're using Core Data. If you're using SQLite directly it'll have to be a lot of manual tinkering and implementation to get it to sync across iCloud.

Comment: The question is about OS x, not iOS, but the rest of your answer is valid.