# Storing data in NSUserdefaults or coredata?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

1. I need to store a dictionary in my app It's life time should be as same as life time of the data stored in NSUserDefaults.
2. There are few ways to achieve  but I am thinking of `core data`, `NSKeyedArchiever` and `NSUserDefaults`.
3. I am going to update this information **frequently** and also dictionary is **not going to be a large data**.
4. **My question is which method is best?** because storing and retrieving from NSUserDefault is costly operation.

Comment: Why `storing and retrieving from NSUserDefault is costly operation`?

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults for small information. Why is using NSUserDefaults a costly operation?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar It is going to be read/ write in the disc right? So It is always expensive operation. If I do this frequently then It is expensive only?

Comment: you can check this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245064/1865424

Answer (score 2):

**-** Core Data seems overkill and is really meant to manage larger amounts of data. It would require you to maintain the entire Core Data stack with persistent store, context, model etc.

**-** NSKeyedArchiver is not meant for frequent changes and certainly much more code than NSUserDefaults.

**+** `NSUserDefaults` is best for the scenario you describe. It is a simple, transparent and sanctioned API, has a fast underlying database associated with it, can be synched via iCloud etc.