# What is the best method to store data for an iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I am planning to create an iPad app that will interact with a set top box(STB). The app will request from the box EPG, recordings library and scheduled bookings. The STB will reply with the details of the EPG( name, desc, time, ID's...), recordings library(not actual recordings just details) and the same with scheduled bookings.
The app will need to update these on start-up and maybe once or twice more. I have been reading through all the different scenarios of people with their different storage problems but I could not decide which the best method would be for me to store these details. Am i right in thinking coreData is the correct/best way to implement this?

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this answer about Core Data & sqlite ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/524301/581190 Also you can stick with dictionary serialization (plist, ...). But it's not good idea to use it for larger chunks of data, because serialized dictionaries must be read at once. So, the answer is - go with Core Data, because it's efficient, not a big overhead and it gives you nice object graph management.

Comment: I hadn't come across that post before I will read that I hope that it is all a bit clearer. Thanks

Comment: Basically you can use plist serialization for small amount of data, like app settings, ... But when you need more data to manipulate, use something better - standalone sqlite (too much writing) or Core Data with sqlite backend, which is the most efficient way.

Comment: I will also need to display the data stored to the user, so they can navigate around the epg and recordings, so would coredata be the best option?

Comment: brilliant thanks for your help. I can now get on and try to understand core data.