# Core Data vs mysql

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios

I already have a **django** application and am trying to develop an iPhone app. I'm using **mysql** as the database for the django app.

Here are some questions I was having :

- Is it necessary to use Core Data for *anything*?
- Can I create a **rest api** to interact with the **mysql** database?
- If so, would there be *any advantage*, at any place or reason, to use **Core Data** in addition to **mysql**. For example, for an app like Pinterest, Tumblr, Facebook, etc. are they using Core Data at all? If so, why and how?

Comment: This question is very borderline non-constructive at the end.  How are we supposed to know why and how other developers do what they do?  The answers, in short, will be 1) No 2) Sure, why not? 3) The hard work will be already done and optimized for you (especially if you use RESTKit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data vs SQLite 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is one way to give you a local database on the phone. With only MySQL on the server, the app cannot access any data when offline. Even in an online-only app, a local cache of some of the data can be useful to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Django,where it has and database-abstraction API that lets you create, retrieve, update and delete objects, iOS has an CoreData. What under-lies is still SQL. From the django end, you need to create an api that returns the class of objects or something. On the iOS side, you have to call this api and parse the data and save it locally using CoreData.

Hope this helps..