# failing to insert data into sqlite database via test case iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, sqlite

I am trying to insert data into one of my tables in a sqlite database via a test case.

Following is the test method:

```
-(void)testAddContact2
{
    [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactName = @"Arvind";
    [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactNo = @"556";
    [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactDob = @"July 10, 1988";
    [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactGender = @"Male";
    [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactEmail = @"arv@bnsad.co";
    [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactLatitude = @"33";
    [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactLongitude = @"44";

    STAssertFalse(([[ContactsModel getInstance] addNewContact] == TRUE),@"passed");
}
```

This is the method I'm trying to test:

```
-(BOOL)addNewContact
{
    BOOL tempFlag = NO;

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    sqlite3 *mDiaryTemp = nil;

    const char *dbpath = [[UseDb getInstance].mDatabasePathDb UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &mDiaryTemp) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CONTACTS VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",
                              [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactName,
                              [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactNo,
                              [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactGender,
                              [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactDob,
                              [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactEmail,
                              [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactLatitude,
                              [ContactsModel getInstance].mContactLongitude];

        const char *insert_stmt1 = [insertSQL1 UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(mDiaryTemp, insert_stmt1, -1, &statement, NULL);

        NSString *tempName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ContactsModel getInstance].mContactName];
        tempName = [tempName stringByAppendingString:@"     "];

        NSString *tempNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ContactsModel getInstance].mContactNo];
        tempName = [tempName stringByAppendingString:tempNo];

        [[ShowContactsViewController getInstance].phoneContacts addObject:tempName];

        NSLog(@"%d",[[ShowContactsViewController getInstance].phoneContacts count]);

        //  NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_step(statement));
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(mDiaryTemp);
            tempFlag = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(mDiaryTemp);
            tempFlag = NO;
        }
    }
    if(tempFlag)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

The following condition always fails: `if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)`
I had posted a similar question earlier, but the issue was resolved when I used shared instances instead of new objects. But here I'm failing to insert even after using shared instances.

Comment: **I bet** your SQLite database is in the app bundle and not in some writable location...

Comment: the database is library/applicationsupport/iossimulator/6.0/<somefoldername>/documents. The project is in MacintoshHD. I don't know if it is in the appbundle as you're talking about.

Comment: No, it isn't - fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, you should consider using CoreData rather than using SQLite directly. CoreData, by default, persists to SQLite and it has much more friendly documentation. Also, since CoreData is not a C API, it will interoperate more nicely with the rest of your Objective-C code. There's also nice Xcode integration when using CoreData, which will let you define schemas easily. You'll also avoid, in many cases, writing SQL queries.

For comparisons between the two [see this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite-3)

Comment: CoreData is not implemented using SQLite. It can optionally persist to SQLite, but it can also persist to other store formats such as XML.

Comment: actually I'm not allowed to use core data in my project. I have to use sqlite directly.

Comment: Corrected the statement about SQLite. That's too bad you have to use sqlite directly. I'd recommend inserting your values into your SQL query and logging it to help debug, like the other answer indirectly suggests.

Comment: The addNewContact method actually works perfectly fine when access it using the view method, where I assign values from the text fields. i have checked the query statement. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: You should look for a problem in your execution of `sqlite3_step();` Assign its return value to a variable so you can see what it's returning. `int return_code = sqlite3_step(statement);`. Then log the return code and compare it to the [possible return codes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)

Comment: Actually "if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &mDiaryTemp) == SQLITE_OK)" is returning false as well. So control isn't going inside at all

Comment: Folks, problem has been solved.. there were some settings to be done in Build settings. I don't exactly know which particular setting made the code work. I'll update once I know.. Thanks everybody for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a semi-colon to the very end of your `insertSQL1`, and see where that gets you. Also be sure that there are no escape characters substituted into this statement.

Edit:

@"INSERT INTO CONTACTS VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")>>>;<<<"...

http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#sql-stmt-list

[image]

Comment: I don't get you. There is already a semi-colon at the end of that statement.

Comment: It does help, in that it gets you one step closer. Seems you have more than one issue.