# Core Data or FMDB?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, fmdb

I am creating an offline application which consist of huge database, I am confused in selecting one of them ***core data*** or ***fmdb*** and also can I use ***join queries*** in core data?

Comment: In Core-Data, you need to use NSPredicate for filtering the records. Core-Data is fast. FMDB is set in its own way.

Comment: @Wolverine according to your experience what should i go with?

Comment: In My experience, It depends on Complexity of relationships between tables/entities. If there is complex relation between tables, then I would use FMDB because it is easy to write query and get data. In case of CoreData, it is fast, most of new apps using Core-Data for storing data, And it is Apple provided concept, Its Good.

Comment: You should go with any of these 2 options, In which you feel confident, level of expertise also matters.

Comment: Go for Core data, Fetching and storing huge amount of data is faster in core data.

Comment: Go with Core Data. However, don't think of Core Data as a database. It is an object graph. And you need to really understand how it works. This is the first sentence on the Core Data from Apple: "Core Data is a rich and sophisticated **object graph management framework** capable of dealing with large volumes of data."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite-3